# How to set zoom in corona sdk mapView

Tags: android, ios, coronasdk

I want to change the zoom settings of corona sdk's mapView, how do I change it's settings?
I have done many research but haven't found 1 yet

Answer (score 3):

```
myMap:setRegion( 3.234542, -12.123456, 0.01, 0.01 )
```

The last two arguments of the above function is **together called the span of the mapview**. Induvidually they are **longitudedelta and latitudedelta**(longitudeSpan/latitudeSpan). They represent how many degrees of longitude and latitude that should be visible on your mapviw.

Consequently,  Setting them both to 1 will cause your mapview to display 1 degree across and 1 degree from top to bottom of the map.

**Increase long/latDelta** --> further from ground

**Decrease** --> closer to ground

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
local myMap = native.newMapView( 0, 0, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
myMap:setCenter( 37.331692, -122.030456, 0.01, 0.01 )
```

You can refer [THIS](http://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/api/type/Map/setRegion.html)